How to change the key's shape in a cryptography progam
I'm implementing a password manager in Python. I included the script in full below.
When executing it, I get the error message below:
fer = Fernet(key)
^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.

Below is my entire script:
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


'''
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.key", "wb") as key_file:
        key.file.write(key)'''


def load_key():
    file = open("key.key", "rb")
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    return key


key = load_key()
fer = Fernet(key)


def view():
    with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User:", user, "| Password:",
                  fer.decrypt(passw.encode()).decode())


def add():
    name = input('Account Name: ')
    pwd = input("Password: ")

    with open('password.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + fer.encrypt(pwd.encode()).decode() + "\n")


while True:
    mode = input("would you like to add a new password or 36"
                 "view existing ones(view, add)? press q to quit").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        break
    if mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("Invalid mode")
        continue


I think it's a problem in the key, which is not in the correct shape.

If you used write_key to create the key and write it to a file, there should be no issues with this script. Note the typo in write_key: key.file should be key_file.

You check this yourself. The data in file key.key should be decodable using base64.urlsafe_b64decode() and the result should be a bytes object of length 32.

"I think it's a problem in the key, which is not in the correct shape." - What do you mean by "shape"? Did you try to check the result that you get after reading the file? What result do you get? Does that look right? Where the error message says "Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.", do you understand what this means? Do you believe that the key meets this requirement? If not, what exactly do you believe you need to know in order to solve the problem?

Did you try to research the error message first, for example by copying and pasting it into a search engine? Do the results give you the needed information? If not, what exactly are you still trying to figure out - what did you learn from the results, and why does this not solve the problem?
